# Retrieving images stored in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

> I have tried to retrieve images I uploaded and saved to mongodb but I am not
>   able to retrieve back the image directly from db. There seems to be a lot of information about
>   uploading files but not a lot of information about retrieving the
>   uploaded images from the db.
>
> I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

This is part of what is saved in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58f2e56fd8ca891e02fc85db"
    },
    "path": "uploads/1492313455338_codi.jpg",
    "filename": "1492313455338_codi.jpg",
    "__v": 0,
    "article": {
        "$oid": "58f2e56fd8ca891e02fc85dc"
    }
}
```

Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

router.js

```
router.post('/blog/article/addPost', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, err) {
  var image = new Image ({
    path: req.file.path,
    filename: req.file.filename
  });
    image.save(function(err, image) {
          //other code
        });
});
```

Part of ejs to upload file

```
<form action="/blog/article/addPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label="name">Add a picture for your article</label>
          <input id="upload-input" type="file" class="form-control" name="image"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

ejs to retrieve file:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="GET" action="/blog/article/<%= image.id %>">
          <img src="<%= image.path %>" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
        </form>
</div>
```

multer configuration:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|wav|tif|gif)$/)) {
      var err = new Error();
      err.code = 'filetype';
      return cb(err);
    } else {
      cb(null, Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove 'public' from the path. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512363/upload-and-retrieve-image-in-node-js) helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have never used multer so I'm not sure how to guide you through it.

However, I do use formidable for uploading images and what have done is I have created a public folder for my images , and every time I upload an image I save the save path in my db, this way you can directly access the dir and implement it in your ejs file.

Hope my answer was relevant.

Good luck

Comment: I was hoping not to store the path, but only the image itself

Comment: You mean you want to store your image in binary? I haven't tried that method but saving the path I personally thing is the better way in terms of scalability.

Comment: I changed the code to save the path instead of saving the images in binary format, but I am still unable to retrieve the images.

Comment: Does your express have a static folder configuration?

Comment: I use this to serve all my static files: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: Can you please share your router config for the page that's supposed to show the image? In your case it should be : router.get('/your route', function to find the image path in your db an and res.render('the ejs page', { returned image object}))